# Pyplot Button widget hover event is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I have the following code. The Button widget is not responding to hover event. What am I doing wrong?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

plot.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
ax = plot.axes([0.5, 0.5, 0.05, 0.05])
Button(ax, "A", hovercolor="red")

plot.show()
```

Comment: what response do you expect? When I run it on my LInux then it changes color on hover.

Comment: I am running on Windows and the color is not getting changed when I move the mouse over it

Comment: code works for me on Linux. On different systems `matplotlib` may use different GUI framework or system widgets and this may not work on some systems.